# Using UNIX sockets for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, unix-socket

Some refs:

- Java UNIX domain sockets (JUDS) - https://github.com/mcfunley/juds
- Java/JNI for unix domain sockets - https://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/

Context:

- I want to use **UNIX sockets** for my Jenkins server
- I have an `nginx` setup with an `upstream` configured to send requests to jenkins.
- I want to to use a unix socket rather than say ... `--httpPort 8080`

Question:

Has anyone done anything similar? My google-fu hasn't helped.

Comment: I understand the appeal of the idea, but in absence of an easy solution, you could also consider binding on the loopback interface only. It gets you just about the same benefits in terms of speed and security.

Comment: I like @zneak's solution. This page (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) describes how to configure Jenkins to only listen to localhost.

Comment: Of course loopback iface. Though going further with the "trust no one" policy, unix socket is the next stop. This is essential if you use reverse proxy authentication, e. i. Jenkins is not protected at all.

Comment: There was a talk on unix sockets for Jetty, which is used with Jenkins https://webtide.com/unix-sockets-for-jetty-9-4/

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/7843b7348e6bd238595d0021e1740ac7e28ba18d